# WARN [middleware:karma]: Invalid file type, defaulting to js. ts

Tags: typescript, webpack, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

When I run unit testing via karma, I got those warning:

```
12 02 2019 14:01:05.740:WARN [middleware:karma]: Invalid file type, defaulting to js. ts
12 02 2019 14:01:05.741:WARN [middleware:karma]: Invalid file type, defaulting to js. ts
```

I assumed that the type of the `karma.conf.js` file caused the issue, so I changed it to `karma.conf.ts`.

However the issue still happened, so it would be great if someone can tell me how to disable this warning.

Below is my karma.conf.ts file

```
module.exports = function karmaConfig(config) {
    config.set({

        singleRun: true,

        frameworks: [
            'jasmine'
        ],

        files: [
            'sdk/**/*.spec.ts'
        ],

        preprocessors: {
            'sdk/**/*.spec.ts': ['webpack', 'sourcemap'],
            'sdk/**/!(*.spec).ts': ['coverage']
        },

        browsers: [
            'PhantomJS'
        ],

        reporters: [
            'progress',
            'coverage',
            'junit'
        ],

        coverageReporter: {
            dir: 'coverage/',
            reporters: [
                { type: 'text-summary' },
                { type: 'html' },
                {
                    type: 'lcov',
                    dir: 'reports',
                    subdir: 'coverage'
                }
            ]
        },

        junitReporter: {
            outputFile: 'reports/junit/TEST-karma.xml',
            useBrowserName: false
        },

        transports: ['polling'],

        webpack: require('./webpack.config'),

        webpackMiddleware: {
            stats: 'errors-only'
        },

        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

    });
};
```

I use webpack `4.16.5` and karma `4.0.0`

Comment: You took the message backwards. It switched to `js` (or "defaulted to js)" because it was a `.ts` file. I agree the `ts` place in the message can be misleading, though.

Comment: Thank you @Seblor, however, the message happened before I switch it to ```.ts``` file. Therefore I switch it to ```.ts``` file to avoid that message. But it didn't work

Comment: Can you give us the file structure you have, and the tools you use ? Maybe other files used by Karma are `.ts` files.

Comment: Thank you @Seblor. This is interesting, I found in karma.js, .ts file is not supported, as ```const FILE_TYPES = [
  'css',
  'html',
  'js',
  'dart',
  'module',
  'dom'
]```. Now I need to know how to get through that issue (I don't want to manually touch that file :D

Comment: There was a fix in karma to display the error better. Any luck in actually debugging it?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same error message, and I believe a similar issue but in my case for .ttf font files causing:

```
19 11 2019 22:12:35.398:WARN [middleware:karma]: Invalid file type (ttf), defaulting to js.
```

From http://karma-runner.github.io/4.0/config/files.html:

> The css and html types create link elements; the js, dart, and module
>   elements create script elements. The dom type includes the file
>   content in the page, used, for example, to test components combinging
>   HTML and JS.

So I believe if you want to add a resource with a different file type as a link it should be type HTML in the files config. The following worked for me:

```
{
    pattern: 'resources/fonts/**/*.ttf',
    type: 'html',
    served: true,
    included: true
},
```

Not sure how .ts files should be included in an HTML page (as shouldn't they be transpiled to JS?) but you could try setting the `type` to `js`.

Answer (score -4):

You are true by `I assumed that the type of the karma.conf.js file caused the issue`
but I think the reason is

> files: [
>               'sdk/**/*.spec.ts'
>           ],
>   I think you should change the `'sdk/**/*.spec.ts'` to `'sdk/**/*.spec.js'`
>   Hope that will help you.

Comment: No, that's not what I wanted to do. The thing is it needs to support .ts, not only .js

Comment: Is there any update on this one? I'm facing the same issue...